# Analysis of series containing Zeta function:

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Consider the given alternating series:

$$f(x) =2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n(x-1)^{2n+1}}{\zeta(-2n-1)}$$

Here, $$a_n= \left(1+\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)^6\left(1-\frac{1}{4n+3}\right)^6\left(\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}\right)^2.$$

How can we calculate the asymptotic of this series as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

Atleast how to compute values of this series for atleast upto $x=100$ accurately?

Comment: This is an observation that might help you: The $2\pi$, $(-1)^{n+1}$, $\zeta$ and $\Gamma$ terms together can be drastically simplified to only $\zeta$ term. Look at the functional equation for the zeta function.

Comment: Should the $k$'s in the formula for $a_n$ be $n$'s?

Comment: @KentaS sorry, corrected

Comment: This function is in some sense similar to the Riesz function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_function). The asymptotic behaviour of the latter heavily depends on the location of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @Gary thank you,noted, but as you can see in the shared link my aim is different.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that this could be an equally difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, using the [formula for the zeta function for even integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers), we have the following:$$\frac{a_n(2\pi)^{2n+2}(-1)^{n+1}}{\zeta(2n+2)\Gamma(2n+2)}=-a_n(2\pi)^{2n+2}\cdot\frac{2(2n+2)!}{(2\pi)^{2n+2}B_{2n+2}}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}=-\frac{4n+4}{B_{2n+2}}a_n,$$

so that

$$f(x)=-4\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{n+1}{B_{2n+2}}a_n(x-1)^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: thank you for the comment but what bout it's values  and asymptotic?

Answer (score 0):

**Not a full answer**. Define
$$
F(x): =  - \frac{{f(\sqrt x  + 1)}}{{2\sqrt {\pi x} }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{a_n \pi ^{2n + 2} }}{{\zeta (2n + 2)\Gamma\! \left( {n + \frac{3}{2}} \right)}}\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}} .
$$
Then, by [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem),
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {x^{s - 1} F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}  = \frac{{a_{ - s} \pi ^{2 - 2s} \Gamma (s)}}{{\zeta (2 - 2s)\Gamma \!\left( {\frac{3}{2} - s} \right)}}.
$$
Using the [Mellin inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem), we then obtain
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{{2\pi \mathrm{i}}}\int_{c - \mathrm{i}\infty }^{c + \mathrm{i}\infty } {x^{ - s} \frac{{a_{ - s} \pi ^{2 - 2s} \Gamma (s)}}{{\zeta (2 - 2s)\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{3}{2} - s} \right)}}\mathrm{d}s} 
$$
with any $0 < c < \frac{1}{2}$. Thus,
$$
f(x) = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_{c - \mathrm{i}\infty }^{c + \mathrm{i}\infty } {(x - 1)^{1 - 2s} \frac{{a_{ - s} \pi ^{2 - 2s} \Gamma (s)}}{{\zeta (2 - 2s)\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{3}{2} - s} \right)}}\mathrm{d}s} .
$$
You may then deform the contour and, depending on the location of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, obtain some estimates for $f(x)$. A crude esimate under the Riemann hypothesis would be $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2 + \varepsilon } )$.